# Apache .htaccess redirect one dynamic url with 2 parameters to another

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need a help on redirecting one dynamic url with parameter to another using the .htaccess.

Old link:

```
https://www.example.com/forum/profile.php?mode=viewprofile&u=7501
```

Here 'u' may varies with different user ids.

New link:

```
https://www.example.com/forum/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=7501
```

Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /fourm/profile\.php\?mode=.+&u=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /forum/memberlist.php [L,R]
```

mod-rewrite automatically appends old querystring to the destination url.